# Why $\rho=\cos \phi$ in $x^2+y^2+(z-\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}$ and $0 \le \phi \le \pi/4$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I need to calculate the volume of cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+(z-\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}$ using spherical coordinates, triple integral and $f(\rho, \phi, \theta)$ notation.

Intuitively, I'd like to say that the radius of the sphere is $0.5$ and this should be the upper bound of $\rho$. However, we need to use $\rho \le \cos\phi$. The algebraical explanation for this is:
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2-z+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow x^2+y^2+z^2=z\\
z=\rho\cos\phi \Rightarrow \rho=z=\rho\cos\phi
$$

I don't understand the reasoning behind this though.

Is it because $\rho$ doesn't start in the origin so we need to make the adjustment?

And secondly, aren't we interested in the angle $\pi/4 \le \phi \le \pi/2$ because this is actually where the cone is situated?

This is the illustration:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to let $\rho$ run to $\tfrac{1}{2}$, the radius of the sphere, if the sphere was centered in the origin. But that's not the case, the center of the sphere is at $(0,0,\tfrac{1}{2})$. A decent sketch helps a lot, I think.

Because the radius is $\tfrac{1}{2}$, the sphere does *touch* the origin so $\rho$ in fact starts at $\rho = 0$ and you have to let it run until it arrives at the top of the sphere (but within the cone). Because of the shifting of the sphere, this is not at a constant distance from the origin but it depends on the angle $\phi$. To find out *how* it depends on it, you use the equation of the sphere and solve for $\rho$, arriving at $\rho = \cos\phi$.

> And secondly, aren't we interested in the angle $\pi/4 \le \phi \le \pi/2$ because this is actually where the cone is situated?

I don't understand how you arrived at these angles; $\phi$ is the angle with the positive $z$-axis? Then you should start at $\phi=0$ and let $\phi$ run until you arrive at the boundary of the cone.

Comment: Thank you so much! My confusion was that $\phi$ angle starts from $x$ axis

Comment: Alright; you're welcome!

Comment: To better to understand the $\rho$ part. Is the upper part of the sphere which is "consumed" by the cone which causes the $\phi$ to change? Or is the lower part of the sphere?

Comment: @Yos I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. You need to set up the bounds so you integrate over the region _inside_ the sphere and _within_ the cone. Is your question about the upper bound of $\rho$, as a function of $\phi$, or about the bounds of $\phi$? In the first case, since you ask about $\rho$, it's not a matter of "$\phi$ changing" but rather how the upper bound for $\rho$ changes _as a function of $\phi$_, and that's the *upper* part of the sphere.